# Is there a way to check if a record exists?

Tags: vapor-fluent

I'm using an external auth system to authenticate users.  But I want to capture the results from that external system and create a record for the users that successfully authenticates and is not already in my local DB.

I've written custom middleware for the external authentication system which is working but I can't figure out how to check if the user already exists in my current DB.  My currently using FluentSQLite as my backing DB.

```swift
let creds = returnFromExternalAuth()
// creds = ["id": "1", "emailAdress": "blah@blah.com", "firstName": "Test", "lastname": "User"]

let user = User.query(on: request).filter(\.ID == id).first()
// returns EventLoopFuture<User?>
```

What I'd like to do is something like

```swift
if let user = try User.query(on: request).filter(\.ID == id).first(){

// Return the found DB user
return User.query(on: request).filter(\.ID == id).first()

} else {

// create db entry for user
// Query and return the newly created DB object
return User.query(on: request).filter(\.ID == id).first() 

}
```

This doesn't work with .first() since it doesn't return an Optional.

Thanks in advance for any help, ideas, or suggestions.

Derek

Answer (score 1):

Update:

I think I got it working here is the solutions for anyone interested.

```swift
return User.query(on: request).filter(\User.ID == id).first().flatMap { optional in
   if let _ = optional {
      return User.query(on: request).filter(\User.ID == id).first()
   } else {
      _ = User(ID: creds["id"], emailAddress: creds["emailAddress"], firstName: creds["firstName"], lastName: creds["lastName"]).save(on: request)
      return User.query(on: request).filter(\.ID == id).first()
   }
}
```

Comment: I think this would execute the queries twice?

Comment: Yes it would.  After working with fluent a lot more I think wouldn't return User.query.  I would

```swift
if let returnUser = optional {
   request.future(returnUser)
} else {
   return User(...).save().flatMap { ... }
}
```
Reduces the # of queries to 1 on success and 2 on failure/create.